# Помогите описать алгоритм, написанный на С++, на великом и могучем

Tags: c++, дискретная-математика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Рылся в сети в поисках алгоритма программы проверки булевой функции на монотонность, к сожалению, нашёл только на С++, но сам им не владею. Буду очень признателен, если опишите чайнику на доступном языке.

Comment: лучше приложить картинку нормально, а не через десять кликов и на сайте, на котором ещё и видеореклама, пробивающаяся через фильтры. Но там же в тексте есть описание на русском языке.

> Функция монотонна, когда выполняется условие
f(xxx0xxx) <= f(xxx1xxx)
> То есть, если для каждого вектора X мы получим множество векторов {X'} таких, что некоторые нули из X там заменены на единицы, и проверим соблюдение этого условия f(X)<=f(X')...

Comment: Простите за кривую ссылку, поторопился. Так я понимаю такой принцип определения монотонный функции, но мне нужен именно алгоритм описанный кодом (

Comment: Код написан достаточно просто. Там нет ничего такого, что бы выходило за пределы формулы, описанной выше. Просто в коде пытаются это дело "преждевременно оптимизировать". Или думаете если просто перевести на русский, (if - если и тому подобное), то оно станет проще?

Comment: Просто мой уровень С++ ниже уровня моря, а алгоритм нужен срочно.

Comment: Если можете описать алгоритм в виде псевдо-кода, буду безмерно благодарен )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если убрать оптимизацию получится следующий псевдокод

```
если длина vec <2 то немонотонна
для i от 0 до длины вектора-1
    для j от i до длины вектора
        если vec[i]>vec[j] то немонотонна
монотонна
```

на а оптимизация сравнивает элементы вектора не сплошняком, а кусками из разных мест и в принципе должна работать быстрее